# Using React + Vite build in Electron without code sharing (different repositories)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, electron, vite

I have a React + Vite application which is in a `webapp` repository and `desktop` repository which will be based on Electron.

I want to keep these both codebases separated but I want to use webapp's build in my desktop application without using any boilerplate like `vite-electron` or `electron-forge`.

I can get the build and somehow sync the latest webapp build in `desktop` repository but I can't run directly `dist/index.html` inside Electron.

It says:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///assets/index-169b8187.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

How should I manage this situation?